# Множественные чекбоксы

Tags: yii

Есть такая задача - записать битовую маску в базу.
Ио есть имеем

```
  ротор, статор, мотор
    +      -       +
```

запишется

```
        101
```

при

```
    ротор, статор, мотор
      +      +       -
```

запишется

```
        110
```

Думаю, идея ясна.
Как это реализовать? Дошел пока до такого:

```
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'estado',  array('checked'=>'checked')); ?>
```

Но как это увязать с формой ввода?

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'m_complect'); ?>
    <?php echo   $form->textField($model,'m_complect',array('size'=>11,'maxlength'=>11)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'m_complect'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: либо кастомный контрол с input[type="hidden"], либо суффиксы к именам чекбоксов и разбор на стороне модели, иначе никак.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как всегда, пришлось самому разобраться:

http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/02/yii-yii-for-dummies-chtmlcheckboxlist.html

Comment: > а в базе: комплектность 1,7,8

рекомендую сейчас же ознакомиться с нормальными формами

Comment: > Как всегда, пришлось самому разобраться

@anunak, Вы не представляете, как это полезно